# Load External Panel To Jquery Mobile Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

JQuery Mobile template which utilises a side panel. For simplicity I want to be able to load this panel from an 'external page' / seperate document so that it can be built once and used on many pages.

A bit of research has resulted in me getting the following code to load a string of html into a variable and then loading that variable into each page as the side panel:

```
/* Get the sidebar-panel as a var */
var side_var = '<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-position="left" data-display="push"><h1>Panel</h1><p>stuff</p></div>';

/* Load the side-panel var to the DOM / page */
$(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function () {
  $.mobile.pageContainer.prepend( side_var );
  $("#left-panel").panel();
});
```

This works perfectly, however it still doesn't address the need to build the sidebar / panel as a separate html file.

A bit more work and I discovered this snippet to load a page into a variable:

```
$.get("http://www.somepage.com", function( side_var ) {}, 'html');
```

So in theory adding the two together should give me the desired result;

```
/* Get the sidebar-panel as a var */
$.get("mypage.html", function( side_var ) {}, 'html');


/* Load the side-panel var to the DOM / page */
$(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function () {
   $.mobile.pageContainer.prepend( side_var );
   $("#left-panel").panel();
});
```

However, all I get when running this is an eternally rotating AJAX loader.

What am I missing &/or doing wrong??

---

**COMPLETE SOLUTION**

Omar's solution below goes most of the way but needs one small but important addition to make the JQM elements display as expected. Here is the complete solution:

```
$(document).one("pagebeforecreate", function () {
  $.get('side-panel.html', function(data) { 
    //$(data).prependTo($.mobile.pageContainer); //or .prependTo("body");
    $.mobile.pageContainer.prepend(data);
    $("[data-role=panel]").panel().enhanceWithin(); // initialize panel
  }, "html");
});
```

<strike>Each element to be enhanced as a JQM element needs the data-theme adding to tell it which theme to use.</strike> Additionally in the JavaScript the initialised panel widget needs to `.enhanceWithin()` in order for the elements to be rendered with the desired style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `$.get()` function should be wrapped in `pagebeforecreate` event, to append contents directly once retrieved. Also, you need to *initialize* retrieved contents.

```
$(document).one("pagebeforecreate", function () {
  $.get('mypage.html', function(data){ 
    $(data).prependTo("body"); // or .prependTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
    $("[data-role=panel]").panel(); // initialize panel
  }, "html");
});
```

Comment: Does anybody else answer question on JQM or have you got exclusive rights ???? ;-)

Comment: @PhillHealey haha..i have an exclusive contract with SO ;)

Comment: @PhillHealey I have update my answer. I have fixed dismissible panel's bug. You need to append/prepend and then enhance/initialize `.panel()`.

Comment: You also need to set the data theme on each widget inside the external panel aswell. Plus once initiated to also need to JQM to enhance the widgets according to the data theme. Ive update my OP with the extra details for reference for others.

Comment: @phillhealey true, however, adding theme to panel is enough, as elements within panel will inherit styles from panel itself :)

Comment: @PhillHealey It's not about who's right or wrong. I'm eager to share every single detail I know, or came to know :)

Comment: I wasn't meaning to sound that way. I simply meant your knowledge of JQuery Mobile is excellent and you've been really helpful. It was meant in a good way.

Comment: @PhillHealey Pls dont misunderstand me too, I meant nothing but a friendly comment. I'm glad I'm able to help and assist, "_sharing is caring_" ;)

Comment: I just noticed this method is resulting in the panel being added multiple times. Ive posted a new question specifically about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634955/restrict-jqm-panel-to-only-1-instance-on-page