# jQuery Mobile Hide Element on External Panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using the following technique to load external panels from HTML:

[Load External Panel To Jquery Mobile Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404657/load-external-panel-to-jquery-mobile-page)

I have a classes defined within my panels:

```
class="signedin"
class="signedout"
```

Based on the following code I hide elements in the panels:

```
function checkStatus() {
    var status = localStorage.getItem("username");
    console.log(status);
    if (status) {
        $('.signedout').hide();
        $('.signedin').show();
        $('#user_name_display').text("Welcome " + status);
    } else {
        $('.signedout').show();
        $('.signedin').hide();
    }
}
```

Loading the panels externally breaks the hiding of the elements. The panels are loaded during pagebeforecreate(). I've tried adding the checkStatus function on pageshow but it still fails to hide the elements:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function () {
  $("body > [data-role='header']").toolbar();
  $("body > [data-role='header'] [data-role='navbar']").navbar();
  // Set based on whether a user is logged in
  checkStatus();
});
```

EDIT:

I tried panel.beforeopen() as well:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", function () {
$( "#settings-panel" ).panel({
  beforeopen: function( event, ui ) {
      checkStatus();
  }
});
});
```

**How do I hide the elements on the external panels based on the checkStatus function?**

Comment: If you run `checkStatus()` before loading the panel, it won't work because the elements you want to show/hide aren't present in DOM by the time you run the function. Run the function after loading the panel.

Comment: I added some detail here. I'm running checkStatus() on pageshow. I've also tried running it after the .get html functions on pagebeforecreate.

Comment: Can you run checkStatus() on the beforeopen or open event of the panel: http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#event-beforeopen

Comment: I've tried that in and outside of a pagebeforecreate function and it still has not affect.